# Expand pandas dataframe from row-wise to column-wise

Tags: python, pandas

I want to expand the columns of the following (toy example) pandas DataFrame,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                   'col2': [1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4],
                   'col3': [3, -1, 0, 5, -2, -3],})


  col1  col2  col3
0    A     1     3
1    A     7    -1
2    A     3     0
3    B     2     5
4    B     9    -2
5    B     4    -3
```

such that it will become row-wise,

```
  col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  col3_1  col3_2  col3_3
0    A     1      7        3      3       -1      0
1    B     2      9        4      5       -2     -3
```

I know that I shall use `groupby('col1')` but do not know how to achieve the desired DataFrame.
Note: The number of elements in each group when we perform `groupby('col1')` are all equal (in this case we have three A's and three B's)

**Edit**:
I managed to do it by the following code, but it is **not efficient**,

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

def func(x, exclude_list):
    for col in x.columns:
        if col in exclude_list:
            continue
        for i, value in enumerate(x[col].values):
            x[f'{col}_{i+1}'] = value
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                   'col2': [1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4],
                   'col3': [3, -1, 0, 5, -2, -3],})

exclude_list = ['col1']
columns_to_expand = ['col2', 'col3']
func2 = partial(func, exclude_list=exclude_list)
df2 = df.groupby(exclude_list).apply(func2)
df2.drop(columns_to_expand, axis=1, inplace=True)
df3 = df2.groupby(exclude_list).tail(1).reset_index()
df3.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df3)
```

which results in,

```
  col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  col3_1  col3_2  col3_3
0    A       1       7       3       3      -1       0
1    B       2       9       4       5      -2      -3
```

**Edit2**: This code, based on `ouroboros1` answer works efficiently,

```
df_pivot = None
for col in columns_to_expand:
    df['index'] = [f'{col}_{i}' for i in range(1,4)]*len(np.unique(df[exclude_list].values))
    if df_pivot is None:
        df_pivot = df.pivot(index=exclude_list, values=col, columns='index').reset_index(drop=False)
    else:
        df_pivot = df_pivot.merge(df.pivot(index=exclude_list, values=col, columns='index').reset_index(drop=False))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update*: the question has been updated to expand *multiple* columns row-wise. This requires some refactoring of the initial answers that were tailored to the initial question, which only required the operation to take place on *one* column (`col2`). Note that the current refactored answers *also* work perfectly fine on a single column. However, since they are a little verbose for that situation, I'm keeping the original answers for just 1 column at the end.

---

###### Answers for expanding multiple columns row-wise

You could use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                   'col2': [1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4],
                   'col3': [3, -1, 0, 5, -2, -3],})

cols = ['col2','col3']

# val count per unique val in col1: N.B. expecting all to have same count!
vals_unique_col1 = df.col1.value_counts()[0]+1 # 3+1 (use in `range()`) 
len_unique_col1 = len(df.col1.unique()) # 2

# create temp cols [1,2,3] and store in new col
df['my_index'] = [i for i in range(1,vals_unique_col1)]*len_unique_col1
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='col1',values=cols,columns='my_index')\
    .reset_index(drop=False)

# customize df cols by joining MultiIndex columns
df_pivot.columns = ['_'.join(str(i) for i in x) for x in df_pivot.columns]
df_pivot.rename(columns={'col1_':'col1'}, inplace=True)

print(df_pivot)

  col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  col3_1  col3_2  col3_3
0    A       1       7       3       3      -1       0
1    B       2       9       4       5      -2      -3
```

2 alternative solutions based on [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) could like this:

- Groupby solution 1

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                   'col2': [1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4],
                   'col3': [3, -1, 0, 5, -2, -3],})

cols = ['col2','col3']

df_groupby = df.groupby('col1')[cols].agg(list)\
    .apply(pd.Series.explode, axis=1).reset_index(drop=False)

# same as in `pivot` method, this will be 3
len_cols = df.col1.value_counts()[0]

# rename cols
df_groupby.columns=[f'{col}_{(idx-1)%len_cols+1}' if col != 'col1' else col 
                    for idx, col in enumerate(df_groupby.columns)]
```

- Groupby solution 2

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                   'col2': [1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4],
                   'col3': [3, -1, 0, 5, -2, -3],})

cols = ['col2','col3']

agg_lists = df.groupby('col1')[cols].agg(list)

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(agg_lists[col].tolist(), index=agg_lists.index) 
       for col in agg_lists.columns]

df_groupby = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

len_cols = df.col1.value_counts()[0]
cols_rep = np.repeat(cols,len_cols)

df_groupby.columns = [f'{col}_{str(i+1)}' for col, i 
                      in zip(cols_rep, df_groupby.columns)]
df_groupby.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

---

###### (Original) answers for expanding single column row-wise

You could use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], 
                   'col2': [1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4]})

# add col with prospective col names (`col1_1,*_2,*_3`) 
# and multiply by len unique values in `df.col1`
df['index'] = [f'col2_{i}' for i in range(1,4)]*len(df.col1.unique())

df_pivot = df.pivot(index='col1',values='col2',columns='index')\
    .reset_index(drop=False)

print(df_pivot)

index col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3
0        A       1       7       3
1        B       2       9       4
```

Alternative solution based on [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) could like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], \
                   'col2': [1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4]})


# create lists of values in `col2` per group in `col1`,
# then expand into multiple cols with `apply(pd.Series), finally reset index
df_groupby = df.groupby('col1').agg(list)['col2']\
    .apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=False)

# overwrite new cols (`0,1,2`) with desired col names `col2_1, etc.`
df_groupby.columns=[f'col2_{col+1}' if col != 'col1' else col 
                    for col in list(df_groupby.columns)]

print(df_groupby)

  col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3
0    A       1       7       3
1    B       2       9       4
```

Comment: in your groupby method, according to this answer: [Split a Pandas column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491399/14627505), it is faster to use `.to_list()` than `.apply(pd.Series)`.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that it doesn't work if we have more columns. I edited my answer to reflect on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution for any number of columns:

```py
def f(group):
    result = (group.set_axis(range(1, len(group) + 1))
                   .T
                   .stack())
    result.index = (result.index
                          .to_flat_index()
                          .map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format))
    return result
```

Specify the columns (as a list) here:

```py
chosen_cols = ['col2', 'col3']
df.groupby('col1')[chosen_cols].apply(f).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```py
  col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  col3_1  col3_2  col3_3
0    A       1       7       3       3      -1       0
1    B       2       9       4       5      -2      -3
```

**Explanation:**

`f` accepts a sub-dataframe: a group (where `'col1'` is the same),
and converts this group into a Series.
When returned, this Series will become the row.

For example:

Let's say that that `f` receives a `group` where `col1` is `'A'`:

```py
   col2  col3
0     1     3
1     7    -1
2     3     0
```

It resets the index (because you want the numbering to start from 1):

```py
group.set_axis(range(1, len(group) + 1))

   col2  col3
1     1     3
2     7    -1
3     3     0
```

After `.T.stack()`, the dataframe becomes a Series with a MultiIndex:

```py
col2  1    1
      2    7
      3    3
col3  1    3
      2   -1
      3    0
dtype: int64
```

This MultiIndex is flattened (into tuples) and the tuple elements are merged together with a '_' in between them:

```py
col2_1    1
col2_2    7
col2_3    3
col3_1    3
col3_2   -1
col3_3    0
dtype: int64
```

That's it! After that, this Series is returned from `f` and becomes a row:

```py
  col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  col3_1  col3_2  col3_3
0    A       1       7       3       3      -1       0
```

---

---

**Previous solution** (it works only for 1 column, so don't use it):

3 steps (using `.groupby`):

- Aggregate all elements of each group into a list:

```py
temp = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(list)
```

```py
col1
A    [1, 7, 3]
B    [2, 9, 4]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

- Expand these lists into new columns:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame(temp.tolist(), index=temp.index)
```

```py
      0  1  2
col1         
A     1  7  3
B     2  9  4
```

- Rename the columns and reset  index:

```py
result.columns = range(1, len(result.columns) + 1)
result = result.add_prefix('col2_').reset_index()
```

```py
  col1  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3
0    A       1       7       3
1    B       2       9       4
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that it doesn't work if we have more columns. I edited my answer to reflect on the problem.